# kea несколько ipv6-сетей на один фейс

Tags: ipv6

не могу найти решение.
вот хочу локальную fc00:, которая всегда есть и ни от чего не зависит. хочу 302:, которая актуальна только когда поднят yggdrasil и обращение идёт внутри её. хочу teredo, которая тоже есть не всегда. и может мой ублюдочный пров что-то своё подкинет. однако, минимум три. адрес из fc00: актуален только локально, адрес 302: актуален только в сети yggdrasil- эти адреса нельзя использовать за пределами их узкого мирка, т.е. с глобальных нельзя к ним и с них нельзя к глобальным. адреса тередо глобальны, но они зависят от ipv4 адреса внешки, который динамика, и их вообще может не быть. к одной сети никак не свести. так как заставить эту фашистcкую поделку учитывать реальность, а не жить в мире религиозных иллюзий её разработчиков?

зы: shared networks- это не про то, это про расширения пула на несколько разных сетей, из которых будет выбран и выдан машине только ОДИН, а мне нужно несколько сразу, так как мои сети живут каждая в своём мире, друг о друге не знают и никак не пересекаются.
определение нескольких сетей в конфиге принимается, но из них всегда выбирается только первая в списке. самое чудовищное в этой ситуации, что в самом начале мне как-то удалось сразу несколько адресов передать на фейс машине, но тот конфиг был утерян и я убей не могу его воспроизвести ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9.17. DHCPv6 Server Limitations
These are the current limitations of the DHCPv6 server software. Most of them are reflections of the current stage of development and should be treated as “not implemented yet”, rather than actual limitations.
**The server will allocate, renew, or rebind a maximum of one lease for a particular IA option (IA_NA or IA_PD) sent by a client. RFC 8415 allows for multiple addresses or prefixes to be allocated for a single IA.**
Temporary addresses are not supported. There is no intention to ever implement this feature, as it is deprecated in RFC8415.
Client reconfiguration (RECONFIGURE) is not yet supported.

будем надеяться, что за оставшиеся полтора месяца они допилят эту пре-альфу до продакшена %D